# How to reload data in UIView

Tags: ipad

I am working on a project in which [image]

As you can see that there is a horizontal view in which images are shown. I have provide facility of scroll. Therefore I have put `UIView` on `UIScrollView` than after `UIButton` on `UIView`. Images on `UIButton` come from plist. Problem is that when I delete the selected image from the plist I am unable to reload data so that deleted image is removed from horizontal view. Can anyone help me in reload data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straight forward solution for reloading the view is to remove all the subviews from the scroll view and then only add the ones that have a corresponding entry in the plist.

You could make a smarter reload that only removes the subviews that have been removed from the plist and then moves the other views, so that there's no gap left after those views. Shouldn't be too hard.